# Virtualenv not isolated

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I am using `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv`. I create a brand new environment:

```
» type python
python is ~/.pyenv/shims/python

» python --version
Python 2.7.12

» pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.1-19-g445d59a

» pyenv virtualenv --version
pyenv-virtualenv 1.0.0 (virtualenv 15.1.0)

» pyenv virtualenv 2.7.14 myenv
New python executable in ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/envs/myenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/envs/myenv/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your ~/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

» pyenv activate myenv 
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
```

The new environment is not clean:

```
» pip freeze
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
ansible==2.1.1.0
apipkg==1.4
argcomplete==0.8.1
argh==0.26.1
astroid==1.4.4
...
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), `--no-site-packages` is by default active:

> Running virtualenv with the option --no-site-packages will not include
>   the packages that are installed globally. This can be useful for
>   keeping the package list clean in case it needs to be accessed later.
>   [This is the default behavior for virtualenv 1.7 and later.]

Why is the new environment not clean?

Comment: Have you sourced the env? i.e. activated the env. For virtualenv you have to source /bin/activate

Comment: @TheyDontHaveIT `pyenv activate` does that ...

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with paths. Neither venv or wrapper wouldn't work.
My guess was that it was because of folders names. I had my username in cyrillic and i thought it was the problem. So i decided to change my username, I followed [this](https://superuser.com/a/955026), created new user with latin symbols in its name and removed the old one. It also removes user files by the way.